# Extend/collapse table except one row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need table be collapsed except one row being clicked. And the code below does the job:

html:

```
<table border="0">
<tr><td>This is row number</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>This is row number</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>This is row number</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>This is row number</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>This is row number</td><td>5</td></tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$("tr").click(function () {
    $("tr").not(this).slideToggle();
});
```

Once visible is only one row would like to expand table back on `mouseover` and this is also easy by:

```
$("tr").mouseover(function(){
        $("tr").show();
});
```

So now, how to make table to be collapsed back on `mouseout` leaving same row visible ?

http://jsfiddle.net/GbRAZ/201/

Will appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: How could `mouseover()` work for an element that's hidden?!

Comment: there is one row left for which `mouseover` work very well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a class to the active row and use that to determine what to show/hide

```
$("tr").click(function () {
    $(this)
       .addClass('active')
       .siblings()
       .removeClass('active')
       .slideToggle();
});

$(".header").mouseover(function(){
    $("tr").show();
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('tr:not(.active)').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gaby-aka-g-petrioli code work perfect, just changing `tr` to `table` in `$("table").mouseover(function()` allows me to change selected row.

Thank you.